# How to pass a certain path to url param in ajax in symfony

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I want to pass a certain path to my url param in ajax in symfony.
I generate a url for the desired path in my controller by the following action:
**$url =  $this->generateUrl('addpermanentsession');**, then I pass the value to my twig template and assign that value to an js varriable inside of script tags.
After that I assign that varriable to my *url* param in ajax.But that doesn't work.
Does someone has an idea, how can I master that.

**My ajax code:**

```
$('.addPermSession').on('click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://caffe.com/addpermanentsession',
            method:'POST',
            data:{myData:'myData'},
            success:function(data){
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller which must edit the request:**

```
/**
 * @Route("/addpermanentsession", name="addpermanentsession")
 */
public function addPermanentSession(){
    if(isset($_POST['myData'])){
        echo json_encode($_POST);
    }else{
        echo 'Is not set';
    }
}
```

**Twig template:**

```
{% extends 'default.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="download" style="display: none;"><a href="list.html"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
            <div class="page-title"><h1>Orders</h1></div>
            <div><a href="staff.html"><span id="edit" class="add-btn" style="display: none;"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a></div>
            <div><a href="order.html"><span id="add" class="add-btn" style="display: none;">+</span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">

            <div id="popup1" class="overlay">
                <div class="popup">
                    <h2>Add permanent session name</h2>
                    <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
                    <div class="contents">
                        <span class="error"></span>
                        <input type="text" name="permanen_session" placeholder="Session name" class="popup-input session_name" maxlength="50">
                        <br>

                        <a href="#" class="popup-btn disabledbutton addPermSession">Add</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row session-details current-session" style="display: none;">
                <span class="archived_sessions"><a href="archive.html">Show Archived Sessions</a></span>
                <div class="delete-session"><span>Archive Session</span></div>
                <div>
                    <div>Session:</div>
                    <div class="session-name"></div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Staff:</div>
                    <div class="staff">

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>Note:</div>
                    <div class="notes"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
            {% if result %}
                {{ path('addpermanentsession') }}
                <div class="row middle session">
                    <div class="archived_sessions"><a href="archive.html">Show Archived Sessions</a></div><br>
                    <label for="add">SESSION NAME</label><br>
                    <span class="session-date">{{ "now"|date("M d Y H:i:s") }}</span><br>
                    <button class="custom">Custom</button>
                    <input type="text" name="session-name" class="field-style fullwidth-input" id="session_name" placeholder="Session name" maxlength="50">
                    <div class="add_new" style="display: block;">
                        <div class="add_new_header">
                            <div><span class="cancel">Cancel</span></div>
                            <div><span title="Add session name"><a class="button addSession" href="#popup1">+</a></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add_new_body">

                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <a href="staff.html" class="next-btn disabledbutton">Next</a>
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <p>There is no result</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

    </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}

    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: you can generate url directly in template {{ path('addpermanentsession') }}

Comment: share the code of template and js

Comment: Ok, thank you for suggestion, but the problem is that the path specifaed this way doesn't 'lead' to the controller, inside of wich our request must be executed.Otherwise we can just write

Comment: $.ajax({
   url:'\addpermanentsession'
});

Comment: //Controller which must edit my request

/**
     * @Route("/addpermanentsession", name="addpermanentsession")
     */
    public function addPermanentSession(){
        if(isset($_POST['myData'])){
            echo json_encode($_POST);
        }else{
            echo 'Is not set';
        }
    }

Comment: //Ajax code

$('.addPermSession').on('click', function(e){
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://caffe.com/addpermanentsession',
            method:'POST',
            data:{myData:'myData'},
            success:function(data){
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });

Comment: Add it to the question

Comment: Ok guys, thank you for any help.It was my mistake.Now is everything ok.